# DataTable Refresh Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to Specific data from one data table to another I Tried this Data is copies in
Table but  Not Displayed in DataList

Can you Suggest me any solution Please?
My Code

```
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt = frmbal.GetAllForum();

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count;i++ )
        dt1.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[i].Caption );

    // dt1.Rows.Clear();
    DataRow []dr=dt.Select("intParentThreadID="+ Request.QueryString["id"]);
    dt1.Rows.Add (dr);
    dt1.AcceptChanges();
    DataList1.DataSource =dt1;
    DataList1.DataBind();
```

this code is in Page Load Event
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `DataRowCollection.Add` method which takes a `DataRow[]` and inserts all rows. The overload that takes an [`object[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx) is to insert one record with these fields.

So this doesn't work:

```
DataRow []dr=dt.Select("intParentThreadID="+ Request.QueryString["id"]);
dt1.Rows.Add (dr);
```

You should use [`DataTable.Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx) and `DataTable.Clone`(to clone the table including columns).

```
DataTable dt = frmbal.GetAllForum();
DataTable dt1 = dt.Clone();
dt1.Merge(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vishal Suthar is good

.But must this code are  inside of !IsPostBack

for sample is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {    
        if (!IsPostBack)    
        {    
         DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
         DataTable dt = frmbal.GetAllForum();
         for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count;i++ )
         dt1.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[i].Caption );
  // dt1.Rows.Clear();
         DataRow []dr=dt.Select("intParentThreadID="+ Request.QueryString["id"]);
         foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
         dt1.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
        } 
         dt1.AcceptChanges();
         DataList1.DataSource =dt1;
         DataList1.DataBind();

        }    
    }
```